# How to update Lynis to the latest version?

Tags: updates, lynis

I'm new with Lynis, the security tool. I installed it with a package manager and check that it is the latest version:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lynis
...
lynis is already the newest version (2.1.1-1).
```

And yet, when I run `lynis audit system`, I get:

```
  - Program update status...                                  [ WARNING ]

      ===============================================================================
        Lynis update available
      ===============================================================================

        Current version : 211   Latest version : 304

        Please update to the latest version for new features, bug fixes, tests
        and baselines.

        https://cisofy.com/downloads/

      ==================================================
```

How can I update Lynis to the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, they expect you to go around your OS vendor to get up-to-date versions.  The error message I see under 2.6.2 is more explicit:

```
Current version is more than 4 months old

Current version : 262   Latest version : 304

Please update to the latest version.
New releases include additional features, bug fixes, tests, and baselines.

Download the latest version:

Packages (DEB/RPM) -  https://packages.cisofy.com
Website (TAR)      -  https://cisofy.com/downloads/
GitHub (source)    -  https://github.com/CISOfy/lynis
```

Because the version offered by your OS vendor may lag behind what's currently available, they offer a number of ways to update it; either retrieve a .deb/.rpm package (for Debian-ish or RedHat-ish distributions), a tarfile of the source, or the github for the source.

For example the [Ubuntu](https://packages.cisofy.com/customers/#debian-ubuntu) package page walks you through the steps required to add the Cisofy repository to your local OS, and then use `apt` to install the package from there.  The other distribution pages show the appropriate steps to use the `apt`, `yum`, or `zypper` package managers, depending on which flavor the OS is.